# React sending props down using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Color-Component that receives colors throw props and does color effect.

```
export enum Colors {
  Blue = "333CFF",
  Yellow = "FCFF33",
  Green = "33FF36",
}

interface IColorProps {
  myColors: Colors ;
}

export const ColorComponent: FunctionComponent<IColorProps > = ( {props: IColorProps } => {
    return (
    <div className={`colorCalss ${props.bgColor}`} />
 )});
```

ParentComponent that sends props to color-component

```
import { ColorComponent, Colors } from "ColorComponent.component";

export const ParentComponent: FunctionComponent<IParentComponentProps> =
(props: IParentComponentProps) => {

        <ColorComponent myColors={Colors.Blue}/>
}
```

The below is what I have placed into the IParentComponentProps

```
export enum Colors {
  Blue = "333CFF",
  Yellow = "FCFF33",
  Green = "33FF36",
}

interface IColorProps {
  myColors?: Colors ;
}

export interface IParentComponentProps {
  colors: IColorProps; 
}
```

I just started working with typescript.

The above Parent component sends props myColors to ColorComponent and its working I can see blue color being apply on my tests.

How can I send props dynamically to ColorComponent, for example lets say the parent.component props.color get different color that could be apply.

When I do something like: "<"ColorComponent myColors={props.colors}/">", I get error.

How can I get props pass down dynamically using enum?

Comment: What is the type of `colors` in`IParentComponentProps`? Is it the same `Colors`  enum?

Comment: I updated the missing IParentComponentProps, as I new to typescript I not sure what should be inputed in color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent interface should have the same color type:

```
export interface IParentComponentProps {
  colors: Colors; 
}
```

This way you will not get the type errors and can pass down the colors prop.

Or pass down the `props.colors.myColors` variable. But be careful it may not exists as you have it optional.

Comment: Im happy it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to send the colors dynamically to the child. Specifically for typescript just make sure all types are consistent.

There's a couple of syntax errors on your example so maybe it's just not compiling for you because of that?

Here's a working sample where parent component dynamically changes the color and sends it to the child every second.

```
export enum Colors {
  Blue = "333CFF",
  Yellow = "FCFF33",
  Green = "33FF36",
}

interface IColorProps {
  color: Colors;
}

export const ColorComponent: React.FunctionComponent<IColorProps> = (props: IColorProps) => {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: `#${props.color}`, height: '100px', width: '100px' }} />
};

const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => {

  const colors = [Colors.Blue, Colors.Green, Colors.Yellow];
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState(0);
  const { current } = React.useRef({ next: function() { } });

  current.next = () => {
    const nextColor = (color === 2) ? 0 : (color + 1);
    setColor(nextColor);
  };

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => current.next(), 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Current color is #{colors[color]}</h1>
      <ColorComponent color={colors[color]}/>
    </>
  );

}
```